# How does delete-keyword work inside this for-each loop?

Tags: c++, foreach, delete-keyword

I am new to C++ and I'm trying to understand how this piece of code works.

```cpp
~List() {
    for(auto& i : nodes) {
        delete &i;
    }
}
```

I have made a Simple Linked List class that has a vector of nodes.

***What I am trying to understand is, if I delete  the current node, how does the for each loop know where the next node is?***

*How I thought it would work is, I would store a pointer to the next node and delete the current one, and repeat this process until the next node is nullptr.*

(Maybe my understanding of vectors is not complete or I don't understand how for-each loops work.)

Can someone who understands how this code works please explain what is going on here?

Comment: *"vector of nodes"* - *Danger, Will Robinson!* If the vector holds `Node*` than your loop should be `delete i;`, if it holds `Node` then you should not be deleting anything at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for(auto& i : nodes) { delete &i; }
```

is syntactic sugar for roughly

```
auto&& range = nodes;
for(auto it = std::begin(range); it != std::end(range); ++it)
{
    auto& i = *it:
    delete &i;
}
```

You're just iterating over `nodes`. Assuming that the destructor of `i` doesn't affect `nodes`, then there's no issue with your code.

Comment: RIGHT!! 
My thinking was flawed. I thought we were going to the next node by looking at i.next, but we at going to the next node through the vector...